# How to fix my app after 'npm audit fix --force'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

For some context, I am a web developer by day, but in the evenings, I work on a personal project using React Native, and I'm still fairly new to it. The app was working totally fine up until a couple of days ago, and I'm not entirely what caused it. Even if I revert back in GitHub, things still do not work.

**Things that I think have caused it are:**

- Running 'npm audit fix --force'
- Or updating node, npm, or expo-cli

**What I've tried so far:**

- I've gone back to a previous commit where the app was definitely working, tried to start the app ('expo start'), but to no avail
- I've made sure the package.json, package-lock.json, and yarn.lock were all reverted, and then ran 'npm install', and the yarn equivalent (I'm aware you shouldn't mix package managers but this has been like it even when the app was working, so fairly sure this isn't the issue)
- Un-ignored node_modules/ in .gitignore, then deleted them from the project, and ran 'npm install', and yarn equivalent
- Tried clearing all caches (npm, metro etc.)
- 'expo doctor --fix dependencies'
- Tried reverting expo-cli to a previous version, same with npm and node
- Debugged the app with remote debugger in Chrome which I'll explain below...

**Symptoms of the issue:**

- It seems to be at build time (I think?) because the app never makes it to any kind of components or screens:[Error in iOS simulator when I try to serve my app using 'expo start' and 'i'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnwbG.png)

r/reactnative - how can I fix my app after 'npm audit fix --force'
Error in iOS simulator when I try to serve my app using 'expo start' and 'i'

- The message I'm getting is 'no stack', because of a "}" symbol (pics will be included), and when I trace this down to its root using the remote debugging in chrome, the caught exception that it paused on was something like 'can't use import statement outside of a module', and the line seems to be referring to Babel module:[Using Expo remote debugger in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OscN.png)

r/reactnative - how can I fix my app after 'npm audit fix --force'
Using Expo remote debugger in Chrome

- When I try to serve the app on web, I get a different Webpack related error (please see screenshots)

I won't put my package.json etc. here because it'll be a wall of text, but here's my repo if anyone would like to see the dev dependencies etc.: https://github.com/braingame-com/bg1

This has caused me so much frustration that I considered just rebuilding the app from scratch because it's not very far along anyway, but I'm really wanting to get my debugging skills up and learn what I had done wrong, rather than taking the easy way out.

What can I try next?

Comment: Did you make sure you're on your original versions of Node, expo-cli, and NPM? Also, I do recommend deleting package-lock.json, yarn.lock, and node_modules, and sticking with either yarn or npm.

Comment: I'm totally up with Abe on this, delete node_modules delete pacakage-lock.json delete yarn.lock, use yarn or npm not both.

Comment: Had few times issues with yarn.lock being incorrect, resulting also that you could not re-clone project from git, the only cure was to remove and install every dependency in project by hand...

Comment: I would advise caution on deleting the lock file. Was this committed to version control and once worked? If so, you know that it is "correct", in the sense that it worked with that exact copy. (However if you are not using version control, and cannot be sure what state the lock file was in, then yeah, delete and re-install).

Answer (score 0):

You should run `rm -rf` in the `node_modules` folder inside your app and then reinstall using `npm install`, that should fix it all!